# App making phone in Call state always

Tags: java, android, kotlin, voip

So recently I have been working on an App that lets the user make Video/audio calls, instant text messages, images .. and I discovered by accident that apparently my my app is always keeping the phone in an "in call" state even when it's closed.

I noticed this after I tried playing a video message on the app and I got the message "can't play video while in call" and then I tried to lower the phone's volume and the default volume shown was the "in call volume" instead of "media volume", like I said this persisted even after closing the app.

did anyone come across anything like this and why it's happening, and I honestly have no idea how it did happen and all my searches lead to nothing.

I wanted to mention that in my video and audio call I do change the speakers mode, can that be the cause if the activity exits without putting the speakers on back on "MODE_IN_COMMUNICATION" even though I have it in my onDestroy ?

Thank you.

Comment: _"even though I have it in my onDestroy"_ An Activity won't necessarily be destroyed when you leave your app. For example, pressing the home button or selecting another app from the Recent Apps list will pause/stop your Activity, but not destroy it.

Comment: @Michael thats true, thank you for reminding me of that.